# Parallel call in iOS using Azure mobile service sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

How can I make parallel calls to Azure server, In client side, I am using Azure Mobile service SDK.

I am doing calls to server like below

```
   [self.table pullWithQuery:query queryId:@"somename"] settings:pullsetting completion:^(NSError *error) {

    // Let the caller know that we finished
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completion(error);
    });
}]
```

For each table/entity, I am making calls like above.
But all the calls are executing serially by Azure.

Is there any way to make it parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, We can not make parallel  requests using azure SDK. When you call `pullWithQuery` method, that operation is added to serial queue internally by azure framework. Here is link to verify implementation files of azure framework :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services